# What should i include for enabling \smallfigscale

Tags: packages

I am having a issue with `width =  \smallfigscale` which used for `\includegraphics`. I think I have the package included, but not installed. What package do I need to install to make it run?

example of use

```
\includegraphics[width=\smallfigscale]{example}
```

Packages used in preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% ------- Enable UTF8 characters ------- %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% ------------ Code Listing ------------- %

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=false,
  language=VHDL,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
  moredelim=**[is][\color{mauve}]{@}{@},
}

% ------- Page layout ------- %
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref} % clickable references
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

% ------- Images ------- %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\DeclareCaptionFont{gray}{\color{gray}}
%\captionsetup{textfont={footnotesize,sc,gray},font={footnotesize,sc,gray}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Test

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command
```

Comment: I implemented `\includegraphics` but I have never heard of `\smallfigscale` it is quite possible that some class or package defines such a length, but how are we to guess.  Presumably whatever documentation you saw that suggested `\smallfigscale` will tell you where it is defined?

Comment: I don't know a package that provides `\smallfigscale`. The only thing I found is https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjr1oryvZHNAhUI6RQKHYmPBEQQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.umn.edu%2F~olver%2Ftex_%2Fo.tex&usg=AFQjCNHqDnOy9yNpBNjM4BQVI_szgegdlw&sig2=I9AxbwDII17CJskp7oI7-g&bvm=bv.123664746,d.bGg. I assume this is something like `\def\smallfigscale{0.8}` etc.

Comment: Never heard of `\smallfigscale`. Where did you find it?

Comment: I was struggling with a compiling a document a colleague of mine had written, and it seems like he used them to insert images inside a tabular.. I am bit uncertain if it is part of usepackage he has included, as none new ones has been added as far i can see.

Comment: @Lamda: Since you have the document of your colleague apparently, you can see which packages are included. You should find `\smallscalefig` then

Comment: Thats just  it.. i cant seem to deduce it.. i will add my preamble.. it might be easier..

Comment: article,I just added it above..

Comment: @Lamda: You're including some packages twice, some at the wrong position, but as far as I can see, none of them defines `\smallscalefig`. Are there some `\input` or `\include` statements in the preamble (or in the document body, `\include` does not work in the preamble, of course)? Perhaps `\smallscalefig` enters this way into your document

Comment: @Lamda: What does `\show\smallfigscale` say in your `.log` file? Is it undefined or something else?

Comment: I am getting this error message ! Undefined control sequence.
`\Gin@@ewidth ->\smallfigscale
l.87 ...llfigscale]{img/images}`

Comment: @Lamda: No, as Werner suggested:, just before `\includegraphics[scale=...]` write `\show\smallfigscale`. If it's undefined, it will show so

Comment: I think, the easiest way to make this compilable, is `\def\smallscalefig{0.3}` (change the 0.3 value to your own needs)

Comment: it skips the line `\show\smallfigscale`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a `\def\smallscalefig{5cm}` (or any other small width value that suits) to provide the possibility to compile the document.

Apparently the `\smallscalefig` macro was once defined somewhere in user code but got lost during copy-and-paste etc.

Comment: exactly what happened :)